# Set the Datatype for a Telerik RadGridView column in these circumstances?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, telerik, radgridview

I've read about how to set the type of a `RadGridView` autogenerated column, but I've created my columns manually at design time and I would like to keep them like that and I need to set the type of the first column as `Integer` and the last column as `Double` to give them the default numerical sorting logic which I suppose the control should use once I assigned those datatypes properly.

I could set the type for a column in these circunstances?

If not, as an alternative maybe I could specify which Telerik's sorting logic should use each column instead writting my sorter(s)?

Comment: Most likely it can determine the type even when autogenerated using `GetType` on the underlying data.  That should be true with any bound datasource, so I am not sure you need to do anything.  Its when you manually populate data that it can get it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each column has a **DataType** property which you can get/set. You can try it.

If not, you can use the [CustomSorting](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-sorting-custom-sorting.html) event and sort the columns as per your requirement.